# Old audio recordings showing language change

Tags: language, famous-people

Languages change with time and pronunciation is one of the things that changes. What is interesting about pronunciation is that direct evidence of this change exists only since we invented audio recording (XIX century).

I was looking for audio evidence of pronunciation change in various languages. In particular I'm interested in finding speeches, conversations, etc. that show how a language used to sound.

What kind of people are the most likely to have such recordings? For USA, president speeches seem to go quite back (Benjamin Harrison). For France oldest president speech I found was from much later (Paul Deschanel). For Russia I found Lenin.

I'm making the assumption that a person's accent is formed in their youth which means that Grover Cleveland is likely to have morn "modern" accent than Benjamin Harrison even though the former became president first. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Second sentence is very misleading. Sure, sound is technically required for it to be "direct" evidence. However, we can see pronunciation changes by tracking rhymes, and via a great deal of other indirect evidence. Recordings are nice, but absolutely not required!

Comment: I think this one should go to linguistics se

Comment: Important: Americans on radio back in the day [had fake accents, FDR for example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_accent) This will certainly color things. Probably  there were linguistic recordings made back then though. If you post on se:linguistics, please let me know.

Comment: Also, the accent used by a POTUS candidate is quite likely to be at least somewhat affected. For a nice modern example, look at the tendency of modern candidates to engage in [gratuitous g-dropping](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/what-kind-of-human-character-or-regional-trait-does-the-habit-of-the-g-dropping). I believe I've even seen g-dropping in speeches held up as evidence someone was running for President prior to their official announcement.

Comment: Dang. Mine was second, so I think I now owe @axsvl77 a soda.

Comment: @T.E.D. Ha! I'll take you up on that

Comment: Audio recordings have existed for 150 years. I'm no linguist, but I think sound shifts often take longer than this to happen.

Comment: Poetry should provide some information on pronunciation (rhyme) and stress (rhythm) at the time it was written.

Comment: A little off topic, but the radio thing wasn't just snobbery, reception was often poor so broadcasters needed to enunciate very clearly and use an accent that would be widely understood

Comment: @AaronBrick Sound shifts can be *much* quicker. Even the Queen now does no longer speak [Queen's English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation#Historical_variation)! Also compare Nazi newsreels with how [*the same guy*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Giese) later spoke (with similar technical equipment) or how today's news presenters speak.

Comment: One shouldn't assume that sound changes will happen at the same rate when a population is exposed to repeated examples of speech from the past as it did when no recordings existed.

Answer (score 3):

You might find this site interesting: https://www.firstsounds.org

> First Sounds seeks out the world's oldest sound recordings—wherever they are. 
>   We rewrote history in 2008 when we discovered and resurrected humanity’s first recordings of its own voice, created in 1860 in Paris by Édouard-Léon Scott de Martinville. Since then, we have identified and played back even older recordings. First Sounds remains the authority on Édouard-Léon Scott de Martinville and his recordings.

In other words, the earliest available recordings for your hearing pleasure are those made by the inventor of the [phonautograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonautograph), the earliest known sound recording device in the late 1850s.

I'd put forward in passing that you can go earlier in time than that by simply visiting Quebec. Linguists widely believe that they speak French with an accent [similar to how it was spoken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology) in the 17th century. Or for that matter, as suggested in the comments, rhymes in poetry give good hints on how people spoke in a given time period.

Comment: Or Afrikaans  vs Dutch, or New Mexican Spanish, or various other isolated populations vs the mother region...

Comment: That too, yeah. I recollect meeting a Colombian one day who put forward that they're the only ones still speaking real Spanish. But I admittedly never dug into whether that claim had merit.